# Basic SDL2 Code which "Stop working" when calling SDL_Quit()

Tags: c++, error-handling

So I got into SDL2 with C++ quite recently and I did this very simple code :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

SDL_Event *event;
bool done = false;

if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
{
    std::cerr << "Problèmes pour initialiser la SDL : " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
SDL_Window *window = 0;
window = SDL_CreateWindow("Mopion", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, WIDTH, HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

if(window == 0)
{
    done = true;
}

while(!done)
{
    while(SDL_PollEvent(event))
    {
        switch(event->type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            done = true;
            break;
        case SDL_KEYUP:
            if(event->key.keysym.sym == SDLK_q)
            {
                done = true;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
SDL_Quit();

return 0;
}
```

While that code executes at first quite well, when I hit the "Q" key, the window closes but I got a Windows Error Window saying that "My program stopped working." which is not very convenient.

Using the debugger, I found that everything is fine until SDL_Quit() is called.

Anyone has any idea why this is going on ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You don't reserve memory for your SDL_Event, and are most probably corrupting your stack. Declare it as automatic and pass it by address to SDL_PollEvent().

Answer (score 0):

You're using uninitialized pointer:

```
SDL_Event *event;
```

And you need to fix some errors:
1. If `SDL_CreateWindow()` returns `0`, it means that there is no window and you must not use `SDL_DestroyWindow()`.
2. You're using events, so you should call `SDL_Init()` like this: `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_EVENTS)`.